# DAG files uploaded into AWS-MWAA-LOCAL aren't showing up on UI

Tags: docker, airflow, docker-desktop, mwaa

i have used this to run airflow locally : https://github.com/aws/aws-mwaa-local-runner
And havent made any major changes. When i tried uploading dag onto the file it isnt showing up on airflow UI.
Repo has provided with one example dag, and even that isn't showing up on airflow UI.

Adding images for reference:

[Airflow UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OJkW.png)

[Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IenhX.png)

I tried checking if paths are entered correctly and also tried restarting my service.

Comment: in your compose-dev.yaml, what is the volume to the dags folder ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If when you start mwaa-local-runner and you do not see an example dag, then this seems odd.

Have you checked the configuration file that mounts the local dags folder [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-mwaa-local-runner/blob/v2.6.3/docker/docker-compose-local.yml) as you can see that it should just mount the local dags folder within the mwaa-local-runner folder.

In the past when I have had issues, it has sometimes because I delete my DAGs from the folder whilst mwaa-local-runner was still running, and it seems to have messed things up. I fixed this by doing to things: 1/I stopped mwaa-local-runner and delete the **pycache** folder in the DAGS folder, 2/I ran mwaa-local-env reset-db to reset the database.

If you are able to share what specific things you changed, that might help.